# How to loop through the array values of an element on a webpage

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have the following code which extracts the value of the [1] item of the class name "oddsType" array from a web-page:

```
a=document.getElementsByClassName("oddsType").item(1).nextElementSibling.innerText
```

However this second portion of the code failed to extract the array of numerical values of the "oddsType" array.

```
for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    console.log(a)
```

How can I extract the other values of the "oddsType".item(1) array?
undefined

Comment: can you share some more detail regarding your html and minimal code to reproduce this issue.?

Comment: Ok, I seem to understand a little better now: you got the `.textContent` from the next sibling of `document.getElementsByClassName("oddsType")[1]` and put it into variable `a`. Can you tell us the format of this `textContent`? Before you can treat `a` like an array it will need to be converted into one. Can you show us the exact result of a?

Comment: @cars10m:  `a=document.getElementsByClassName("oddsType")[1].nextElementSibling.innerText
"3.90"
for (i=0; i<a.length; i++);`
code returns "undefined" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined at <anonymous>:1:18"

Answer (score 0):

The following will probably work (considering your success with the first expression):

```
var collection=document.getElementsByClassName("oddsType");
for (var i=0;i<collection.length;i++) console.log(collection[i].textContent);
```

A slightly more modern (ES6) approach would be:

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName("oddsType")].forEach(el=>console.log(el.textContent));
```

The second version does not pollute your global scope with any variables like (`collection`, and `i` in the first version)

Comment: The code you suggested only displayed all the elements with the class name "oddsType". I need a code to display the array contents of item(1) of the "oddsType" element on the web-page.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to get all values of elements which has the "oddsType" class.

```
let odds = document.querySelectorAll('.oddsType')
let oddsArray = Array.from(odds)
let valuesArray = oddsArray.map(x => {
    return x.textContent.trim()
})
```

This will extract all values of elements to an array. You can change to fit your needs.